# Coffeescript inheritance & eventhandler: Why is the context changed?

Tags: inheritance, coffeescript, event-handling

I have a coffeescript class "OutlayForm" and a subclass "EditOutlayForm". In the superclass an eventhandler (convert_amount) is bound to an inputfield. When creating an object of the superclass everything works fine, but when creating an object of the subclass and triggering the eventhandler it seems like the context is lost.

An error tells me that in convert_amount @amount_field is 'undefined' and console.log(this)
gives me the inputfield instead of the object, although I used the double arrow (=>)

my code:

```
class window.OutlayForm
  ...

  init: (@wrapper) =>
    @bind_buttons()

  bind_buttons: =>
    @amount_field = @wrapper.find('input[name="outlay[amount]"]')
    @amount_field.on('keydown', @convert_amount)

  convert_amount: =>
    #some converting on @amount_field

class window.EditOutlayForm extends window.OutlayForm
  constructor: (@outlay) ->
    @super

  bind_buttons: =>
    super

  #ajax callback:
    @wrapper = $('<div class="edit_outlay_form"></div>')
    @outlay.before(@wrapper.append(data))
    @bind_buttons()
```

Has anybody an idea what I did wrong?

EDIT:

First of all: I use Rails 3.2.12, with the coffee-rails gem (3.2.2) and the jquery-rails gem.

I found the source of the error, but couldn't fix my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/fYDJD/7/

If I run this fiddle, I the console shows me "sub", as I expected.
But if I run this same code on my server, I got "super". Everything I changed was to call

```
new D
```

in the $.ready() function. Is there any possibility that the error comes from that or does it certainly come from my coffeescript version? (That I can't change, because it's already the newest rails gem)

Comment: Is your situation analogous to http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/fYDJD/ but not working?

Comment: @muistooshort When I call `super` in 'bind_buttons' in the subclass it is the situation as you showed and it works fine (in the superclass 'bind_buttons' `@wrapper` is the object as set in the subclass ajax callback). I think the problem is the eventhandler...

Comment: Can you modify the jsfiddle to match your situation? Nothing beats a simplified demo when you're looking for help :)

Comment: @muistooshort here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/fYDJD/2/ thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry, this is it: http://jsfiddle.net/fYDJD/3/

Comment: When I use http://jsfiddle.net/fYDJD/3/, I get `D`s in the console as expected. Are you perhaps using an older version of the CoffeeScript compiler to compile your CoffeeScript to JavaScript?

Comment: Oh, there was a misunderstanding. The script in jsfiddle works fine as it should be. I put the comment in to show you where the error occurs in my script, but I don't know what I did different...

Comment: I think the binding behavior and implementation has changed, compare what your `coffee -c` produces for that fiddle's CoffeeScript with what "TRY COFFEESCRIPT" on http://coffeescript.org gives you. You could always manually set up the binding just like you would in JavaScript too.

Comment: Try to make your examples shorter. Also mention which framework (in your case apparently jQuery) you are using could help getting answers.